# How to zoom chart specific area in Excel Using Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hy Everyone,

I have a sheet with chart that has many values with X-Axis. These values are many in numbers some time I feel difficult to view them, So I want to zoom the any area of the chart by selecting any where in the chart. I used recorded macro that only zoom  sheet not Chart / Graph. But I want a macro that can zoom any specific area of the chart or graph any where I click or select..

Here is pictures of the sheets...[image]
[image]

Comment: Plz any suggestion

Comment: Not sure a zoom is possible, but maybe to change the values of your chart cam do the same effect.

Comment: Any solid solution?

Comment: Like a Zoom Lens or magnifier Macro?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to limit the x-axis (minimum and maximum) and probably limit the max value of the y-axis. This way it will only show a part of the data within the chart which might result in a better resolution to view then. But there is no built-in zoom like you described. Therefore you will need to code that on your own.

*(Sorry for the german screenshot …)*
[image]

As you see in the example above. I have total data in x-axis from `0` to `450` and in the second chart I limited the x-axis from `100` to `200`. Both charts have the same source data, but the second only shows a part of the first.

Comment: This data is on daily basis, how can I minimum the scale while I need data on daily basis for review and analysis on specific date?

Comment: I know it is possible but need to little more effort of macro code....I will try to research more and more. It is not an impossible case.

Comment: @ShakeelAhmadMscit No one is doing all the work for you. No one will post a "solution" that you just copy and paste. It is up to you to do the work. At least try to implement some Idea, then edit your original question showing what you have already done and explain where you got stuck and you might get help with your specific issue then. Just saying "Please give me a solution" doesn't work, I showed you one possible solution but it's up to you to implement it. You didn't show any effort yet to do the work yourself.